# Spring Bean Creation of one Interface depending on Condition

Tags: java, spring, conditional-statements

My goal is to have two bean implementations which are used depending either based on property or existens of a class in classpath. What I tried is ConditionalOnPropery, see below, but did not work.

I have an interface like

```
public interface ApplicationConfigurator {

    void configure(WicketApplication wicketApplication);

}
```

and two implementation classes

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value = "environment",
        havingValue = "client",
        matchIfMissing = false
)
public class OfflineApplicationConfigurator implements ApplicationConfigurator {

    @Override
    public void configure(WicketApplication wicketApplication) {

    }
}
```

And

```
@Component
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
            value = "environment",
            havingValue = "server",
            matchIfMissing = false
    )
public class OnlineApplicationConfigurator implements ApplicationConfigurator {

    @Autowired
    private LsgConfiguration configuration;

    @Override
    public void configure(WicketApplication wicketApplication) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer");
            configuration.setHttpSchema(new TomcatConnectors().getHttpConnector().getScheme());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | ApplicationConfigurationException exception) {
            configuration.setHttpSchema("http");
        }
    }
}
```

My configuration is xml based and looks like:

```
<bean id="onlineApplicationConfigurator" class="com.kion.lsg.service.core.web.config.OnlineApplicationConfigurator"/>
<bean id="offlineApplicationConfigurator" class="com.kion.lsg.service.core.web.config.OfflineApplicationConfigurator"/>
```

And now I get the error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [....service.core.web.config.ApplicationConfigurator] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: onlineApplicationConfigurator,offlineApplicationConfigurator
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Are u specifying your conditional variable 'environment ' in application.yml ? as both these are component it should get auto scanned no need to declare in XML file. You can enable debug mode to see conditional evaluation report which will more more insight.

Comment: I specify it within the context.xml of tomat and/or with -Denvironment=server. I have xml based connfiguration in my old legacy project

Comment: Have u tried debug mode , which gives conditional evaluation report ? What version of Spring boot r u using ? Just try printing value of environment variable , is it getting picked up ?